What are message and sendmail packages for?
As I finally decided to manage emails with GNU Emacs, and to do that via notmuch, I had to understand many things about emailing.
After 2 days of reading and configuring I came up with the following setup:


Email Server: Receives and relays emails. Most email servers are run by email service providers such as Gmail, GMX, etc.
Maildir: A local folder where emails are stored according to the Maildir format.
mbsync:  Syncs Maildir with the Mail Server via IMAP.
IMAP: Internet Message Access Protocol.
notmuch: Indexer, search engine, and tagger that works with Maildir
msmtp: SMTP client that sends email to SMTP servers.
SMTP: Simple Mail Transfer Protocol.
org-msg.el: An email composer that can handle org format and convert it to html
nomuch.el: A MUA (Message User Agent) or email client.
FCC: File Carbon Copy.
message.el:
sendmail.el:

I still have to find out how to manage multiple mail accounts, automate Maildir sync, and crypt password, but I guess that most of the implementation of what I wanted is done.
However, even if I set the value of some variables from message.el and sendmail.el, I can't understand the relationship between these two packages and what is their role. Both have the same description, which is quite vague:

This mode provides mail-sending facilities from within Emacs.


They are mutually exclusive: sendmail.el implements mail-mode and is the older implementation; message.el implements message-mode and is the newer one (it was written to be used by GNUS and the message.el sources are still under the lisp/gnus directory in the Emacs source tree). If you have a choice, I recommend you use message.el and read the Message manual for what it provides.

Thank you @NickD! At the moment I only use send-mail-function and sendmail-program from sendmail.el. Is there an equivalent in message.el? Are all the sendmail.el variables covered by message.el?

In message.el there is a (require 'sendmail) line. From what I understand from your comment, I infer that this requirement is only temporary. Am I correct?

No - in fact, those two are used by message.el. So I was probably a bit too categorical when I said they are mutually exclusive.

(We had crossed comments here - my previous comment was in answer to your first comment above). I think the (require 'sendmail) in message.el is there to pick up the two variables you mentioned. I don't think that's temporary, but I might very well be wrong.
